# What does _X_ mean from Google Ngram?

Tags: google-ngram-viewer

[This symbol](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=_X_&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C_X_%3B%2Cc0) occurs roughly 1 percent of the time from the Google's english corpus. It uses the tagging format described [here (scroll down)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/info), but there is no specific documentation for the `_X_`.

Answer (score 1):

### Looks like an error

I searched a bunch of variations of this, and I concluded this is some sort of error with Ngram.

You can get results for a [bunch of garbage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%26%208%20%26%2C_8_%2C_%208%20_%2Cq%20p%20q%2C_y_%2C_Y_&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=0), though not usually with as much frequency:

[image: search: & 8 &,8,_ 8 _,q p q,y,Y]

Searching for that garbage plus `_X_` in English Fiction (2009) [returns no results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%26+8+%26%2C_8_%2C_+8+_%2Cq+p+q%2C_y_%2C_Y_%2C_X_&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=en-fiction-2009&smoothing=0). If it was some sort of advanced search operator, it would probably still return results. If it was something that really occurred in English 1% of the time, it would still return results.